# Deploying war to payara throws severe errors: Unable to obtain CDI 1.1 utilities for Mojarra

Tags: java, cdi, weld, payara, payara-micro

since this is happening in a pretty large code base and I don't know how to even start isolating the issue, I can't really give a small reproducing example.
Maybe you can help me further debug the issue and step-after-step being able to provide a small scenario with the same symptoms.

The following errors appear when deploying the .war file in payara micro `5.2021.2`:

```
[2021-04-26T10:10:09.096+0000] [] [SEVERE] [] [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.application.view] [tid: _ThreadID=1 _ThreadName=main] [timeMillis: 1619431809096] [levelValue: 1000] Unable to obtain CDI 1.1 utilities for Mojarra

[2021-04-26T10:10:09.109+0000] [] [SEVERE] [] [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.flow] [tid: _ThreadID=1 _ThreadName=main] [timeMillis: 1619431809109] [levelValue: 1000] Unable to obtain CDI 1.1 utilities for Mojarra

[2021-04-26T10:10:09.181+0000] [] [SEVERE] [NCLS-CORE-00026] [javax.enterprise.system.core] [tid: _ThreadID=1 _ThreadName=main] [timeMillis: 1619431809181] [levelValue: 1000] [[
  Exception during lifecycle processing
org.glassfish.deployment.common.DeploymentException: CDI deployment failure:Error while loading class fish.payara.security.oauth2.OAuth2AuthenticationMechanism$Proxy$_$$_WeldSubclass -- Error while loading class fish.payara.security.oauth2.OAuth2AuthenticationMechanism$Proxy$_$$_WeldSubclass
    at org.jboss.weld.resources.ClassTransformer.getBackedAnnotatedType(ClassTransformer.java:186)
    at org.jboss.weld.resources.ClassTransformer.getBackedAnnotatedType(ClassTransformer.java:194)
    at org.jboss.weld.resources.ClassTransformer.getEnhancedAnnotatedType(ClassTransformer.java:232)
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.producer.SubclassedComponentInstantiator.initEnhancedSubclass(SubclassedComponentInstantiator.java:86)
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.producer.SubclassedComponentInstantiator.<init>(SubclassedComponentInstantiator.java:79)
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.producer.SubclassedComponentInstantiator.forInterceptedDecoratedBean(SubclassedComponentInstantiator.java:63)
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.producer.BeanInjectionTarget.initializeAfterBeanDiscovery(BeanInjectionTarget.java:121)
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.producer.InjectionTargetInitializationContext.initialize(InjectionTargetInitializationContext.java:42)
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.producer.InjectionTargetService.initialize(InjectionTargetService.java:63)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.WeldStartup.deployBeans(WeldStartup.java:481)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.WeldBootstrap.deployBeans(WeldBootstrap.java:86)
    at org.glassfish.weld.WeldDeployer.processApplicationLoaded(WeldDeployer.java:521)
    at org.glassfish.weld.WeldDeployer.event(WeldDeployer.java:433)
    at org.glassfish.kernel.event.EventsImpl.send(EventsImpl.java:131)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.ApplicationInfo.load(ApplicationInfo.java:346)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.prepare(ApplicationLifecycle.java:570)
    at org.glassfish.deployment.admin.DeployCommand.execute(DeployCommand.java:576)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:556)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:552)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:360)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:551)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$3.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:582)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$3.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:574)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:360)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:573)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1497)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.access$1300(CommandRunnerImpl.java:120)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1879)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1755)
    at com.sun.enterprise.admin.cli.embeddable.CommandExecutorImpl.executeCommand(CommandExecutorImpl.java:183)
    at com.sun.enterprise.admin.cli.embeddable.CommandExecutorImpl.run(CommandExecutorImpl.java:96)
    at fish.payara.boot.runtime.BootCommand.execute(BootCommand.java:69)
    at fish.payara.boot.runtime.BootCommands.executeCommands(BootCommands.java:136)
    at fish.payara.boot.runtime.BootCommands.executeCommands(BootCommands.java:130)
    at fish.payara.micro.impl.PayaraMicroImpl.bootStrap(PayaraMicroImpl.java:1049)
    at fish.payara.micro.impl.PayaraMicroImpl.create(PayaraMicroImpl.java:226)
    at fish.payara.micro.impl.PayaraMicroImpl.main(PayaraMicroImpl.java:213)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at fish.payara.micro.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:50)
    at fish.payara.micro.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:114)
    at fish.payara.micro.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:73)
    at fish.payara.micro.boot.PayaraMicroLauncher.create(PayaraMicroLauncher.java:88)
    at fish.payara.micro.boot.PayaraMicroLauncher.main(PayaraMicroLauncher.java:72)
    at fish.payara.micro.PayaraMicro.main(PayaraMicro.java:467)
]]

[2021-04-26T10:10:09.182+0000] [] [SEVERE] [] [javax.enterprise.system.core] [tid: _ThreadID=1 _ThreadName=main] [timeMillis: 1619431809182] [levelValue: 1000] Exception while loading the app
```

The app is not deployed as a result.

What I did so far:

- Looked into the dependency tree and made sure the war doesn't contain any dependencies that would interfere with stuff that payara provides
- Tried googling the combination of payara and these issues. Not much luck. JBoss/WildFly stuff came up but I couldn't really connect it to my issue
- Looked into the source code of javax faces to see where the actual `Unable to obtain CDI 1.1 utilities for Mojarra` message is thrown.
- Trying to understand why that code is even loaded, but I couldn't find any connection.

Here are the dependencies:

```
mvn dependency:tree | grep compile
[INFO] +- INTERNAL_LIB:INTERNAL_LIB:jar:1.0.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.antlr:antlr4-runtime:jar:4.9.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- commons-beanutils:commons-beanutils:jar:1.9.4:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- commons-collections:commons-collections:jar:3.2.2:compile
[INFO] +- com.auth0:auth0:jar:1.29.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:jar:4.9.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:jar:1.4.10:compile
[INFO] |  |     \- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:jar:1.4.10:compile
[INFO] +- io.jsonwebtoken:jjwt:jar:0.9.1:compile
[INFO] +- com.auth0:jwks-rsa:jar:0.17.1:compile
[INFO] +- redis.clients:jedis:jar:3.5.2:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.apache.commons:commons-pool2:jar:2.6.2:compile
[INFO] +- com.google.guava:guava:jar:30.1.1-jre:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.google.guava:failureaccess:jar:1.0.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.google.guava:listenablefuture:jar:9999.0-empty-to-avoid-conflict-with-guava:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:jar:3.0.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.checkerframework:checker-qual:jar:3.8.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.google.errorprone:error_prone_annotations:jar:2.5.1:compile
[INFO] |  \- com.google.j2objc:j2objc-annotations:jar:1.3:compile
[INFO] +- joda-time:joda-time:jar:2.10.10:compile
[INFO] +- software.amazon.awssdk:s3:jar:2.16.44:compile
[INFO] |  +- software.amazon.awssdk:aws-xml-protocol:jar:2.16.44:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- software.amazon.awssdk:aws-query-protocol:jar:2.16.44:compile
[INFO] |  +- software.amazon.awssdk:protocol-core:jar:2.16.44:compile
[INFO] |  +- software.amazon.awssdk:arns:jar:2.16.44:compile
[INFO] |  +- software.amazon.awssdk:profiles:jar:2.16.44:compile
[INFO] |  +- software.amazon.awssdk:sdk-core:jar:2.16.44:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.reactivestreams:reactive-streams:jar:1.0.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- software.amazon.awssdk:auth:jar:2.16.44:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- software.amazon.eventstream:eventstream:jar:1.0.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- software.amazon.awssdk:http-client-spi:jar:2.16.44:compile
[INFO] |  +- software.amazon.awssdk:regions:jar:2.16.44:compile
[INFO] |  +- software.amazon.awssdk:annotations:jar:2.16.44:compile
[INFO] |  +- software.amazon.awssdk:utils:jar:2.16.44:compile
[INFO] |  +- software.amazon.awssdk:aws-core:jar:2.16.44:compile
[INFO] |  +- software.amazon.awssdk:metrics-spi:jar:2.16.44:compile
[INFO] |     +- io.netty:netty-codec-http:jar:4.1.61.Final:compile
[INFO] |     +- io.netty:netty-codec:jar:4.1.61.Final:compile
[INFO] |     +- io.netty:netty-transport:jar:4.1.61.Final:compile
[INFO] |     |  \- io.netty:netty-resolver:jar:4.1.61.Final:compile
[INFO] |     +- io.netty:netty-common:jar:4.1.61.Final:compile
[INFO] |     +- io.netty:netty-buffer:jar:4.1.61.Final:compile
[INFO] |     +- io.netty:netty-handler:jar:4.1.61.Final:compile
[INFO] |     +- io.netty:netty-transport-native-epoll:jar:linux-x86_64:4.1.61.Final:compile
[INFO] |     |  \- io.netty:netty-transport-native-unix-common:jar:4.1.61.Final:compile
[INFO] +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-sqs:jar:1.11.1001:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-core:jar:1.11.1001:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- software.amazon.ion:ion-java:jar:1.0.2:compile
[INFO] |  \- com.amazonaws:jmespath-java:jar:1.11.1001:compile
[INFO] +- com.cloudbees.thirdparty:zendesk-java-client:jar:0.14.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.asynchttpclient:async-http-client:jar:2.12.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.asynchttpclient:async-http-client-netty-utils:jar:2.12.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- io.netty:netty-codec-socks:jar:4.1.53.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- io.netty:netty-handler-proxy:jar:4.1.53.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- io.netty:netty-transport-native-kqueue:jar:osx-x86_64:4.1.53.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- com.typesafe.netty:netty-reactive-streams:jar:2.0.4:compile
[INFO] |  \- com.damnhandy:handy-uri-templates:jar:2.1.8:compile
[INFO] +- com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs:jackson-jaxrs-json-provider:jar:2.12.3:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs:jackson-jaxrs-base:jar:2.12.3:compile
[INFO] |  \- com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-jaxb-annotations:jar:2.12.3:compile
[INFO] +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:jar:2.12.3:compile
[INFO] +- com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-joda:jar:2.12.3:compile
[INFO] +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:jar:2.12.3:compile
[INFO] +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:jar:2.12.3:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:jar:3.12.0:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:jar:4.5.13:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:jar:4.4.13:compile
[INFO] |  \- commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.2:compile
[INFO] +- com.googlecode.concurrent-trees:concurrent-trees:jar:2.6.1:compile
[INFO] +- com.warrenstrange:googleauth:jar:1.5.0:compile
[INFO] +- commons-codec:commons-codec:jar:1.15:compile
[INFO] +- com.timgroup:java-statsd-client:jar:3.1.0:compile
[INFO] +- org.influxdb:influxdb-java:jar:2.21:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:jar:2.9.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-moshi:jar:2.9.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- com.squareup.moshi:moshi:jar:1.8.0:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.msgpack:msgpack-core:jar:0.8.21:compile
[INFO] +- com.opencsv:opencsv:jar:5.4:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.commons:commons-text:jar:1.9:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.apache.commons:commons-collections4:jar:4.4:compile
[INFO] +- nl.big-o:liqp:jar:0.7.9:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.jsoup:jsoup:jar:1.11.3:compile
[INFO] +- net.jodah:failsafe:jar:2.4.0:compile
[INFO] +- com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:jar:4.9.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.squareup.okio:okio:jar:2.8.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-common:jar:1.4.0:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:jar:1.4.10:compile
[INFO] |     \- org.jetbrains:annotations:jar:13.0:compile
[INFO] +- commons-io:commons-io:jar:2.8.0:compile
[INFO] +- io.searchbox:jest:jar:2.0.4:compile
[INFO] |  +- io.searchbox:jest-common:jar:2.0.4:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- com.google.code.gson:gson:jar:2.6.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore-nio:jar:4.4.4:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpasyncclient:jar:4.1.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.lucene:lucene-core:jar:5.5.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.lucene:lucene-backward-codecs:jar:5.5.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.lucene:lucene-analyzers-common:jar:5.5.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.lucene:lucene-queries:jar:5.5.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.lucene:lucene-memory:jar:5.5.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.lucene:lucene-highlighter:jar:5.5.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.lucene:lucene-queryparser:jar:5.5.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.apache.lucene:lucene-sandbox:jar:5.5.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.lucene:lucene-suggest:jar:5.5.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.apache.lucene:lucene-misc:jar:5.5.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.lucene:lucene-join:jar:5.5.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.apache.lucene:lucene-grouping:jar:5.5.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.lucene:lucene-spatial:jar:5.5.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.lucene:lucene-spatial3d:jar:5.5.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- com.spatial4j:spatial4j:jar:0.5:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.elasticsearch:securesm:jar:1.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.carrotsearch:hppc:jar:0.7.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat:jackson-dataformat-smile:jar:2.8.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat:jackson-dataformat-yaml:jar:2.8.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat:jackson-dataformat-cbor:jar:2.8.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.yaml:snakeyaml:jar:1.15:compile
[INFO] |  +- io.netty:netty:jar:3.10.6.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.ning:compress-lzf:jar:1.0.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.tdunning:t-digest:jar:3.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.hdrhistogram:HdrHistogram:jar:2.1.6:compile
[INFO] |  +- commons-cli:commons-cli:jar:1.3.1:compile
[INFO] |  \- com.twitter:jsr166e:jar:1.1.0:compile
[INFO] +- org.elasticsearch:elasticsearch:jar:2.4.4:compile
[INFO] +- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.30:compile
[INFO] +- ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:jar:1.2.3:compile
[INFO] +- ch.qos.logback:logback-core:jar:1.2.3:compile
[INFO] +- io.sentry:sentry-logback:jar:4.3.0:compile
[INFO] |  \- io.sentry:sentry:jar:4.3.0:compile
[INFO] +- com.abusix.util:rate-limiting-logback-filter:jar:0.1.0:compile
```

I would be super happy if someone could give me a hint on what could be the issue or how to better debug the situation.

Thank you!

Edit 1:

As suggested in the comments I debugged payara and put a breakpoint at https://github.com/weld/core/blob/052861a964e78f2f65a97706fe1b181c9d7ce128/impl/src/main/java/org/jboss/weld/resources/ClassTransformer.java#L186 to find out the cause (because it's not properly logged in the current version of payara apparently).

The cause is a `ClassNotFoundException`.

```
"java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Whitelist enabled, but class [org.eclipse.microprofile.config.Config] is not whitelisted"
```

I will do some further investigation into that.

Edit 2: Seems like there was some kind of a hidden dependency to microprofile.config (not in our code, and not in one of our dependencies. at least not explicitely).

It helped to add:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.eclipse.microprofile.config</groupId>
    <artifactId>microprofile-config-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Will see if that fixed everything and write an answer then.

Comment: The stack trace of the "Error while loading class" exception is missing "Caused by: xyz" blocks. The answer is over there.

Comment: @BalusC Thanks I was thinking the same. There are no "Caused by: xyz" blocks in my output though. Any idea how to turn on more verbosity or something, so that they are included?
The deployment is done postboot via `deploy --force --enabled=true [...]` in the container.

Until now all issues when booting failed had proper stack traces and I was able to easily find out the cause. In this case it's just not there.

Comment: How does the same deployment behave when deployed against a full fledged Payara web server instead of a Payara Micro?

Comment: Same error. Slightly different stack trace, but still no cause included. It also fails at the same line. Here: https://github.com/weld/core/blob/052861a964e78f2f65a97706fe1b181c9d7ce128/impl/src/main/java/org/jboss/weld/resources/ClassTransformer.java#L186

Comment: Put a breakpoint there and inspect `e`. It represents the cause and thus contains the answer.

Comment: I will give it a shot and will add any findings here. Thank you

Comment: Updated the post with some debugging results. Will now look further into the cause.

Answer (score 2):

We had a whitelist set to help with some classloading issues: https://blog.payara.fish/resolving-library-conflicts-with-class-whitelisting

When upgrading payara we, for some reason, now depend on microprofile.Config to be available.

This can be fixed by either adding it to the whitelist:

```
<glassfish-web-app>
  <whitelist-package>org.eclipse.microprofile</whitelist-package>
</glassfish-web-app>
```

Or adding the api as a dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.eclipse.microprofile.config</groupId>
    <artifactId>microprofile-config-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.0</version>
</dependency>
```